# Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 10: 10

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to create a Lazy Loading Widget but it gives me this error:

> Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 10: 10

this is where the build error occurres:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LazyLoadScrollView(
      isLoading: isLoading,
      onEndOfPage: () => _loadMore(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return data[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is my entire script:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lazy_load_scrollview/lazy_load_scrollview.dart';

class LazyLoad extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;

  const LazyLoad({Key? key, required this.children}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LazyLoadState createState() => _LazyLoadState();
}

class _LazyLoadState extends State<LazyLoad> {
  List<Widget> data = [];
  int currentLength = 0;

  final int increment = 2;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadMore();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _loadMore() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    for (var i = currentLength; i <= currentLength + increment; i++) {
      data.add(widget.children[i]);
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      currentLength = data.length;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LazyLoadScrollView(
      isLoading: isLoading,
      onEndOfPage: () => _loadMore(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return data[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code works! But I wanted to get rid of the error somehow.
I am already using itemCount: in the ListView.builder ad culdn't find out what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a condition like so - `if(i < widget.children.length) data.add(widget.children[i]);`

Comment: You should do something like,
for (var i = currentLength; i <= min(currentLength + increment,widget.children.length) ; i++) {  }